# Comparación de fechas trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente trigger que lo que tiene que hacer es bloquear si insertan una fecha diferernte a la actual, es decir si insertan un documento  con una fecha de ayer o de antier o diferente a la de hoy, como puedo hacer esta comparación.

**`IF (@Fecha <> GETDATE())`** así trato de insertar y sale el mensaje sea cual sea la fecha que ponga como puedo decir que si es diferente a la fecha de hoy salga este mensaje.

```
CREATE Trigger  [dbo].[FECHAS BLOQUEADAS]
On [dbo].[tblencinventarios] FOR INSERT 
AS
/*
   Autor: Juan Esteban Grialdo Giraldo 
   Copyright (c) 2020  AnT
   All Rights Reserved
*/
DECLARE @Fecha datetime
   SELECT @Fecha = MAX(INSERTED.fecha) 
     FROM inserted
       IF (@Fecha <> GETDATE()) BEGIN
         ROLLBACK  TRANSACTION  
              RAISERROR ('NO SE PUEDE HACER ESTE DOCUMENTO CON UNA FECHA DIFERENTE A LA ACTUAL' , 16, 1 )
                    END
```

Comment: y en que formato esta @fecha?

Comment: El tipo de dato es  DATETIME

Comment: y las horas son iguales? horas, minutos y segundos?

Comment: Son diferentes creo que por eso no meda

Comment: 2020-12-01 08:28:03.650  este es el formato con el que queda la fecha si es diferente a esa fecha no puede dejar pasar el documento pero si es igual si

Answer (score 2):

Parece que el problema que tienes viene del tipo de dato que estas comparando, difícilmente podrás encontrar una fecha igual a la de un `GetDate()`, puesto que tiene una precisión de milisegundo.

Si quieres comparar fechas (sin horas) debes convertir las fechas. Una forma de hacerlo es mediante un `CAST` pasando el `DATETIME` A `DATE`. De manera que la parte de tu código que compra fechas quedaría así:

```
DECLARE @Fecha date    SELECT @Fecha = MAX(CAST(INSERTED.fecha as DATE)) 
        FROM inserted
        IF (@Fecha <> CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) BEGIN
```

De esta forma puedes conocer si tienes registros de ayer o antes.